# Angular 2 - How to inject service in a e2e test with protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, angular2-services, e2e-testing

For my automation testing, I need to inject service to get the data and check if I am on the correct page or not. I dont want to use DOM for this, I want to check through my service.

```js
import { CurrentEntityService } from "./../../app/services/current-entity.service";
        describe("App component", () => {
            it("check current entity name", inject([CurrentEntityService], (currentEntityService: CurrentEntityService) => {
                  browser.get("/tenants/");
                  expect(currentEntityService.entityName.value).toEqual("value");
               }));
        });
```

When I run the test, the web driver runs  but it gives the following error

```js
 [17:15:38] I/testLogger - [firefox #01] PID: 28196
 [firefox #01] [17:15:34] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
 [firefox #01] [17:15:37] I/runnerCli - undefined
```

Do I need to do anything extra for using services in my e2e test? Why am I seeing this undefined error? Am I doing something wrong while injecting the service. Please point me out in the right direction for injecting a service in protractor test in angular 2. I am new to e2e testing.

Comment: Protractor tests don't run within the Angular app, so it doesn't make sense to try to use Angular's DI in them.

Comment: e2e tests are black box. The thing you're trying to do belongs to unit tests.

Comment: @estus Thank you for that info. But what if I want to check if I am on the correct page or not and I dont want to use DOM for this. –

Comment: This is a matter of methodology. You need to use DOM for this in Protractor e2e tests. If there's a need to make e2e tests more thorough and rely on internal mechanisms, this means that your unit/integration tests aren't strong enough.

Comment: @estus Thank You so much for this piece of information and pointing me in the right direction.